# Javascript - Nested parent/child array recursive function that flattens parent only

Tags: javascript, recursion, underscore.js

I have a multidimensional nested parent/child array as follows:

```
{
  parent: {
     name: "foo"
  },
  children: [
    {
      parent: {
         name: "asdf",
      },
      children: []
    },
    {
     parent: {},
     children: []
    },
    {
     parent: {},
     children: []
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

What I want to do is apply a recursive function on this array, to flatten only the parent property and keep children as-is, in order to get something like this:

```
 {
  name: "foo",
  children: [
    {
      name: "asdf",
      children: []
    },
    {
     children: []
    },
    {
     children: []
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I tried using underscore.js but I am unable to find a recursive function that could do the trick. Any thoughts?

Comment: are there some array in it? for children maybe?

Comment: Yes children is an array. I've edited my question, thanks for the remark!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach by iterating the array and updating the wanted properties.

If a children is found, iterate again.

```js
var array = [{ parent: { name: 'a', surname: 'b', }, children: [{ parent: { name: 'c', surname: 'd', }, children: [{ parent: { name: 'e', surname: 'f' } }], childrenName: 'v', childrenSurname: 'w' }], childrenName: 'x', childrenSurname: 'y' }];

array.forEach(function iter(object) {
    if (object.parent) {
        object.name = object.parent.name;
        object.surname = object.parent.surname;
        delete object.parent;
    }
    object.children && object.children.forEach(iter);
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

hope this `recurse` function is what you need

```
const recurse = (data) => {
    for(let i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++){
        if(data[i]['parent']){
            data[i]['name'] = data[i]['parent']['name']
            delete data[i]['parent']
        }
        if(data[i]['children']) recurse(data[i]['children'])
    }
}
```